# Excel VBA formula insert in current cell

Tags: excel, vba

Due to beginner for VBA, I am in a difficult to find this codes.
I need to create 'Command Button' to insert formula according to 
current cell location. 
Eg. If current cell location is S7, need to get formula in to it '=K7*L7'. 
Current cell location change all the time. Multiplication of Column K and L fixed.
Please help me to write this codes.

Comment: does the Row (7 in your example) change?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Looking for something like this `Selection.Formula = "=K" & Selection.Row & "*L" & Selection.Row`?

Comment: I had to use `FormulaLocal ` instead of `Formula` to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign below code to command button

```
Sub Insert_Formula
    n = Selection.row
    Selection.Value = "=K" & n & "*L" & n
End Sub
```

---

In VBA, Selection will get the selected cell properties.

For example, if you select **S7**,

```
n = Selection.Row
```

Then **n** will be **7**

```
Selection.Value = "=K" & n & "*L" & n
```

Above will set selected cell's formulat to **=K7*L7**

---

In addition, if you want the button to work on selected range which is more than one cell,

```
Private Insert_Formula_Multi_Cells
    For X = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        n = Selection.Row + X - 1
        Selection.Range(Cells(X, 1), Cells(X, Selection.Columns.Count)) = "=K" & n & "*L" & n
    Next X
End Sub
```

**Selection.Rows.Count** Gets number of rows selected.

**Selection.Columns.Count** gets number of columns selected

Comment: =K7*L7 I need to multiply by (-1), to convert to minus number. How to do it?

Comment: Since it's multiplication, just add **"-"** before L7 
**=K7*-L7**

Comment: It works like this  Selection.Value = "=-K" & n & "*L" & n

Comment: Either Before **K** or **L**  should have same output

Comment: It didn't work =K7*-L7, but before K minus sign  works.

Answer (score 0):

to get current location in excel you can use `ActiveCell.Address` command.

Below code first gets current selected cells address and then multiplies with K(11) and L(12) columns to print value in active cell.

```
Sub acell()
  Dim s As String
  s = ActiveCell.Address
  Range(s).Select
  Range(s).Value2 = Cells(2, 11) * Cells(2, 12)
  Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

You can add them in loop as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't get formula "=K7*L7"

Comment: you replace 2 with 7 in above code like Cells(7, 11) * Cells(7, 12) . Now it will show result of multiplication in active cell